# What is the right way to download image and persist with Spring webflux

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, spring-webflux, reactive

I use Spring 3.0.0 with webflux in Kotlin. The task is to download image from the url and simply persist it to the relational database. Below is the code snippet, but it doesn't work correctly as the function allways provide an empty byte array. It must be related to the subscribe method of `DataBufferUtils.write`, but I am not sure when should dataBuffer should be released.

Probably the best way is to make the whole stack reactive, but persistence layer is non-reactive and the function must return blocking result, i.e. ByteArray.

```
   fun downloadImage(url: String): ByteArray? {      
        val outputStream = ByteArrayOutputStream()
        val dataBuffer = webClient.get().uri(url)
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToFlux(DataBuffer::class.java)

        outputStream.use {
            DataBufferUtils.write(dataBuffer, it)
                .subscribe(DataBufferUtils.releaseConsumer())
        }

        return outputStream.toByteArray()
    }
```